# Javascript insert an object to an array like this [{...}, {...}]

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Suppose I have a variable called `var testVar = [];`
And I have a data in ajax like this

```
{
  "Country": "ALA Aland Islands",
  "CountryCode": "AX",
  "Slug": "ala-aland-islands",
  "Population": 100000,
  "Teenagers": 50000,
  "Mid": 20000,
  "Seniors": 30000
},
{
  "Country": "Afghanistan",
  "CountryCode": "AFR",
  "Slug": "afghanistan",
  "Population": 200000,
  "Teenagers": 50000,
  "Mid": 100000,
  "Seniors": 50000
}
```

I'm trying to do a for loop and insert the population per country in the array (testVar)
by doing it like this

```
function obj(key, val) {
this.key = key;
this.val = val;
}
for(i=0;i<data.lenght;i++){
    var x = new obj("y",data[i].Population);
    testVar.push(x); 
}
```

although the above works, it still didn't achieve what I'm trying to do.
what i want the data to look like should be something like this

```
[{...}], [{...}] instead of [obj,obj]
```

Comment: And where are you printing the data? Console? Console is a browser's part and every browser has its own implementation for it

Comment: `testVar.push({ y: data[i].Population })` ?

Comment: @Sirko That seem to be a better implementation but will not solve issue. An alternate for your approach would be `testVar = data.map(({ Population }) => ({ y: Population }) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### It's a fairly simple solution

All we do is `map` the `ajax response` to only the population key.

```js
let data = [{
    "Country": "ALA Aland Islands",
    "CountryCode": "AX",
    "Slug": "ala-aland-islands",
    "Population": 100000,
    "Teenagers": 50000,
    "Mid": 20000,
    "Seniors": 30000
  },
  {
    "Country": "Afghanistan",
    "CountryCode": "AFR",
    "Slug": "afghanistan",
    "Population": 200000,
    "Teenagers": 50000,
    "Mid": 100000,
    "Seniors": 50000
  }
];

console.log('Standard Approach');
console.log(data.map((location) => ({
  Population: location.Population
})))
   
console.log('Property Destructuring');
console.log(data.map(({Population}) => ({
  Population
})))

console.log('Using Y && Standard Approach');
console.log(data.map((location) => ({
  y: location.Population
})))

console.log('Using Y && Property Destructuring');
console.log(data.map(({Population}) => ({
  y: Population
})))
```